# output code into formatted web page

Tags: c#, .net

hey guys. i was wandering if anyone knew how to create code so that the console is not opened, rather a formatted web page.

any suggestions will be much appreciated!

regards

```
namespace Grades
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\t\tValue Distribution\n");

            String text = File.ReadAllText(@"values.dat"); //obviously change file path again

            char[] c = text.ToCharArray(); //convert to char array

            var g = c.OrderBy(a => a); //order array

            foreach (char group in g)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group.ToString()); //loop, displaying ordered array
            }
            //
            int aCount = c.Count(a => a == 'A'); //count all 'A' instances
            int bCount = c.Count(b => b == 'B'); //count all 'B' instances
            int cCount = c.Count(cc => cc == 'C'); //count all 'C' instances
            int dCount = c.Count(d => d == 'D'); //count all 'D' instances
            int eCount = c.Count(e => e == 'E'); //count all ''E' instances
            int fCount = c.Count(f => f == 'F'); //count all 'F' instances

            //
            Console.WriteLine("\nA = {0}", aCount);
            Console.WriteLine("B = {0}", bCount);
            Console.WriteLine("C = {0}", cCount);
            Console.WriteLine("D = {0}", dCount);
            Console.WriteLine("E = {0}", eCount);
            Console.WriteLine("F = {0}", fCount);

            //multiplying amount in each group by 2
            aCount = aCount * 2;
            bCount = bCount * 2;
            cCount = cCount * 2;
            dCount = dCount * 2;
            eCount = eCount * 2;
            fCount = fCount * 2;

            //outputs graph display
            Console.WriteLine("\n0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100");
            Console.WriteLine("|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |");
            Console.WriteLine("**************************************************");

            //outputs each grade according to the multiplied amount and is therefore displayed with asteriks
            Console.Write(new String('*', aCount)); Console.Write(" A\n");
            Console.Write(new String('*', bCount)); Console.Write(" B\n");
            Console.Write(new String('*', cCount)); Console.Write(" C\n");
            Console.Write(new String('*', dCount)); Console.Write(" D\n");
            Console.Write(new String('*', eCount)); Console.Write(" E\n");
            Console.Write(new String('*', fCount)); Console.Write(" F\n");
```

Comment: What is the context of this code output?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: if you see the above, i have added my current code, and as you can see the information is coming from a file named values.dat. regards

Comment: @climbage it took a minute to figure this out. He wants to generate a webpage to display his results. @cameron, can you use ASP.NET? It will make things easier, because then you won't be forcing a particular browser to open, but will be letting them choose their own browser and letting them visit your webpage. That's what I would do. But it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a a file "output.html" and write to this file, instead of your console. Obviously, you'll also want to write slightly different output, i.e. HTML markup etc. That's the solution to create a single web page from an otherwise console-style program.

If you want to create web page output on a regular basis, you should let the whole thing run in IIS and use ASP.NET such that you can automatically serve your output to a web request, and take advantage of, e.g., its HTML templating functions.

I know that's very general, but maybe it's a starting point from which you can either explore further or specify your problem!

Comment: i have no prior knowledge of ASP.NET, all i know is C#, and even that is limited... i would love to learn about using ASP.NET to create webpages because i know that there are many advantages of this.

Comment: well ASP.NET is a framework which can (I'm even tempted to say should) be programmed in C#. The easiest way to get in touch with it might be to download the free Visual Developer from Microsoft. Basically you drag'n'drop your web UI together and then put your code into events tied to the UI elements (say, a click event of a button or whatever). So you could just go ahead and paste your code into some Click event and replace the Console.write... by assignments to your UI objects. Just give it a try, the biggest step you've already mastered by learning C#!